# What is "abstract" ergodic theory?

Tags: probability, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

This is just a question about the usage of the term "abstract".

What kind of questions in ergodic theory is considered "abstract" and what's a "regular" question? From some seminars it seems that there are two schools of thoughts but I am unable to make a clear distinction.

For example consider Ornstein's isomorphism theorem. Is this a result is abstract ergodic theory?

Answer (score 1):

"Abstract" ergodic theory does not use differentiable assumptions, only measurable ones.

Removing differentiability assumptions is done in order to have easier problems, but the idea is then to get back to differentiable systems, because they come from differential equations. See the differentiable realization problem: problem 2 of http://www.personal.psu.edu/axk29/pub/5problems-expanded.pdf

"abstract" is in the sense of "non-concrete", "non-physical", "non-practical".

Answer (score 0):

Well here is what I think abstract ergodic theory is: Classification of measure theoretic dynamical systems upto metric isomorphisms. Usually this is very difficult outside the world of pure point spectrums. So one uses additional smoothness assumptions for "regular" ergodic theory.